# PHP display a generated image in mail

Tags: php, html, email

So when users sign up, they get an email, and I'm trying to add an image to that email. That image is dynamically generated using php, so its not a static url. The code works, but when I add it to the email code, the image shows up blank. I know the code works because I have echo'd the body, and the image showed up fine in my browser but empty in the email (i have a border around the image, the border shows up, inside is empty).

```
$img = "<img src='../inc/barcode.php?id=".$regid."' style='padding:5px; border:2px dashed '/>";
```

elsewhere

```
$body .= $img;
```

So does anyone know why the image won't display, and how I could make it so it does?

Also, another question to kind of go off this, how do I display a generic url for the image so that instead of /img.php?id="" it just reads /img.php or something.

Comment: how is the image placed in the email, as a link, attachment or embedded? If it's a link show an example of it `/img.php?id=1` is local `http://domain.com/img.php?id=1` is not

Comment: @Waygood Edited it in. Its embedded

Comment: It's a __link__ to the parent folder of the computer thats reading it. Put the full URL including the domain name in there to

Comment: write one or search the internet for a two way encryption function (ie encode/decode) then encode `id` before sending and decode in barcode.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391132/two-way-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative links, not absolute.

```
$img = '<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/inc/barcode.php?id='.$regid.'" style="padding:5px; border:2px dashed" />';
```

Comment: Oh right.. is there a way to "obfuscate", I guess, the url so that the id="" doesn't show up?