# Storing hashed ID in DB and fetching it or creating hashed ID in code itself and use it?

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have two way of doing handling hashed IDs but need your opinions on which one would better over another and why? I'm **only** interested in the logic rather than what technology I used for hashing or table data type etc!

I'm going to generate an URL to handle deleting a product and the URL will be like this (last segment is hashed (SHA1) product.id):

```
...../delete/product/123c45c789ds654dedkjfghr87frd
```

**SCENARIO 1:**
Store hashed ID in table and use it like this:

**> Query:**

```
DELETE ...... WHERE hash_id = '$url_hash_id'
```

**> Table:**

```
products
id - INT
hash_id - VARCHAR(40)
```

**SCENARIO 2:**
Do not store hashed ID in table but generate it everytime when you create the URL and use it like this:

**> Query:**

```
DELETE ...... WHERE SHA1(id) = '$url_hash_id'
```

**> Table:**

```
products
id - INT
```

**What I can think of are:**

1. Scenario 1 - Table gets bigger (*potentially whole DB because I might end up implement same column for all the tables*) but hashing process is run once.
2. Scenario 2 - Less table space used but `mySql SHA1()` function and
   `php SHA1()` functions are called everytime we need it.

Comment: You might find this helpful even though it doesn't directly answer your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391132/two-way-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with scenario 1 simply because `WHERE SHA1(id) = '$url_hash_id'` will not use the mysql index. With a large number of records the table scanning will kill you more than the extra overhead of storing the `hash_id` and an index for that column.