# Insert hash id in database based on auto-increment id (needed for fast search?)

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, hash

I'm writing a simple flask-restful API and I need to insert some resource into database. I want to have hash id visible in the URL like this `/api/resource/hSkR3V9aS` rather than just simple auto-increment id `/api/resource/34`

My first thought was to use [Hashids](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python) and just generate the `hash_id` from auto-increment `id` and store both values in the database, but the problem is that I would have to first `INSERT` new row of data, `GET` the `id` and then `UPDATE` the `hash_id` field.

Second attempt was to generate `hash_id` (e.g. sha1) not from `id` but some other field that I'm passing to databse and use it as a primary key (get rid of auto-inc id), but I fear that searching and comparing string each time rather than int will be much, much slower.

What is the best way to achive desired `hash_id` based URL along with acceptable speed of database `SELECT` queries?

I think this is the most related [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088619/storing-hashed-id-in-db-and-fetching-it-or-creating-hashed-id-in-code-itself-and), but it doesn't answer my question.

Major technology details: Python 3.6, flask_mysqldb library, MySQL database
Please let me know if I ommited some information and I will provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a decent solution myself in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548531/5939565)

> Use `cursor.lastrowid` to get the last row ID inserted on the cursor
>   object, or `connection.insert_id()` to get the ID from the last insert
>   on that connection.

It's per-connection based so there is no fear that I'll have 2 rows with the same ID.

I'll now use previously mentioned by myself [Hashids](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python) and return hashed value to client. Hashids can be also decoded and I'll do it each time I get a request from url with this hash id included.

Also I found out that MongoDB database generates this kind of hashed id by itself, maybe this is a solution for someone else with similar problem.